# Model OnDelete event?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a simple model that looks like this:

```
public class ImageFile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ImageMeta Meta { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUploaded { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way I can add some kind of "OnDelete" event hook so that whenever a model is deleted via `db.Images.Remove(imageFile);` or whatever other means, I can delete the associated file?

Comment: Are you looking to also detect deletions that are cascaded? That is my trouble.

Comment: @Derrick: Yeah, that would be helpful. I haven't touched this project in awhile, but ideally there would be a hook that would always run on deletion so it never got out of sync.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `SaveChanges` method of your context to hook up to delete entities.

```
public class GalleryContext : DbContext
{
     public override int SaveChanges()
     {
          var deletedImages = ChangeTracker.Entries()
              .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted && e.Entity is ImageFile)
              .Select(e => e.Entity).Cast<ImageFile>();

          foreach(var image in deletedImages)
          {
              // delete file here or call a method on image
          }

          return base.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Comment: What can we do if the delete failed when a transaction is rolled back later?